# Why would one use AsyncTasks when you can use Services?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

When you learn to develop for Android, you learn that if there's any type of process -that takes more that 5 seconds- running inside the ui thread, the system will show the infamous ANR message. That's when they introduce the evil monster... AsyncTask. At first you see this class as your savior, but then you realize it's the biggest problem in development... Handling rotation or ui events becomes so problematic, it's even painful.
What do you guys think about it... are AsyncTasks worth the trouble? Any other method that makes it less of a problem to perform long running tasks regardless of screen rotation?
I guess you'll probably say, hey why don't you just make it a Service... Yeah that's a solution, but then let's go to my real question. Why don't we just use services and stop using AsyncTasks completely... Are they useful at all?

Answer (score 2):

While developing it is always good to choose the suitable component for the execution. You need to clear your requirement and according to it you can choose between a `Service` or an `AsyncTask`.

- A service is an Android component that lives independently from any other components. Activities may come and go, but services can stick around, if you wish. They serve a number of roles, from managing state that multiple activities rely upon to serving as cron jobs to handling longer app widget updates.
- AsyncTask is a class that arranges to do some work off the main application thread. From the implementer and user of the AsyncTask, how it performs that bit of magic is not generally important. In reality, it uses a thread pool and work queue. AsyncTask uses a Handler to help arrange for select bits of work to be done on the main application thread (e.g., notifying the user of progress updates).

For more clarification see the difference between them.

[image]

Comment: The interesting part is when you mentioned [quote]Activities may come and go, but services can stick around, if you wish[/quote]. So that means if I intend to have rotation enabled, AsyncTasks should be out of the question because of the fact that Activities are recreated when you rotate. right?

Comment: you can set it not to re-create by `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Please note, AsyncTasks *do not* go away if you rotate the screen, they will continue to execute. If you'd like to get a handle to them after the rotation you can store them in Object returned by Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(). After your Activity is re-created you can get this object from Activity.getLastNonConfigurationInstance().

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks and Services are not peers. Either might invoke the other, their purposes are different. I have just a few things to add to Lucifer's answer.

A key thing to remember is that if your process is in the background, hosts a Service, and is killed, that Service will be reincarnated at some point. This is not the case for an AsyncTask that may be running in a process when it is killed. This means that work being done in a Service is guaranteed to make forward progress in the future (although its not guaranteed when). If you have work that *must* be done, better to do it in a Service.

Calls to Service.onStart and Service.onStartCommand happen on the process' main thread. If you block this for a long time, you'll get the same "app not responding" dialog. As a result, an AsyncTask can be a great thing to use inside a Service to do the real work.

I tend to use AsyncTasks initiated from an Activity for things related to the UI. These are often things that aren't required work and whose work can be easily redone in the future. For example, this might be reading a bunch of images off disk or make a calling to a web service to see if the user has any notifications. This work can be done again, and if the UI is destroyed because the process is killed the work probably needs to be done again anyway.

If on the other hand you want to say upload a group of photos to the web as soon as possible, I'd farm this out to a Service which will use one or more AsyncTasks to do it. This is work I want to get done and want to be resumed if it gets interrupted. If you're going to use a Service, consider using an IntentService so that your Service stops when its work is done.